# Java TicTacToe: Computer's or Player's first move

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am very new to Java and I am trying to code a very simple TicTacToe game. I would like to give the possibility either the computer or the player to do the first move. If the computer begins as first, it should start at the corners of the grid, that is, to avoid the positions with a 2 within. Unfortunately, the program is really slow and it seems that the input at the very beginning of the code is not recognized instantly by the scanner. Moreover, I don´t know how to solve the fact that, before I enter in the infinite while loop, if the player starts as first, it will be asked him two times which position he will choose between 1 and 9. I am not asking to solve the problems but could you please give me some hints on how I can go further and how I can change my logic? Thank you very much in advance.

```
/**
 * 
 */

import java.util.*;




public class TicTacToeNeu {

    static public int randomNumberX = 0;
    static public int randomNumberY = 0;
    static public char  playerPiece = 'X';
    static public char computerPiece = 'O'; 
    static char[] [] board = {{'_','|','_','|','_'},{'_', '|', '_','|','_'},{' ','|',' ','|',' '}};
    static int playerPosition;


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner imputScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Would you like to start?"); // "Would you like to start (Yes/No)"               
        String firstImput = imputScanner.nextLine(); // input user              

        while(!firstImput.equals("Yes") && !firstImput.equals("No")) {  
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.out.println("Would you like to start? (Yes/No");
            firstImput = imputScanner.nextLine();
        }


        if (firstImput.equals("No")) { // Computer starts
            randomNumberX = randomizer();
            randomNumberY = randomizer();
            while (randomNumberX == 2 || randomNumberY == 2) { // 
                randomNumberX = randomizer();
                randomNumberY = randomizer();
            }
            board[randomNumberX][randomNumberY] = computerPiece;    
            printBoard(board);
        } 
        
        else{
            printBoard(board);
            System.out.println("Give a position (1-9)");// Player starts 
        }

        while(true) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give a position (1-9)"); //choose the position from 1 to 9
        int position = scan.nextInt();
        playerMove(board,position);
        System.out.println("Now is computer´s turn");
        computerMove(board);        
        }   
        
        
    }
        
        
    

    private static int randomizer() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    }
    
    
    public static boolean invalidMove() {
        
    return false;   
    }

    
    
public static void computerMove(char [] [] board) {
        
        char character = 'O';
        
        int position = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
    
        boolean result = validateMove(position, board); // controls open space on the board
        
        
        while(!result) {
        
            position = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            validateMove(position, board);
            
        }
        switch (position){
        case 1:
            board[0][0] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 2:
            board[0][2] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 3:
            board[0][4] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 4:
            board[1][0] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 5:
            board[1][2] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 6:
            board[1][4] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 7:
            board[2][0] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 8:
            board[2][2] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 9:
            board[2][4] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }
    }
    
    
    public static boolean validateMove(int zug, char[][] board) {
        switch (zug){
        case 1:
            if(board[0][0] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return invalidMove();
            }
        case 2:
            if(board[0][2] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return invalidMove();
            }
        case 3:
            if(board[0][4] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return invalidMove();
            }

        case 4:
            if(board[1][0] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return invalidMove();
            }
        case 5:
            if(board[1][2] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return invalidMove();
            }
        case 6:
            if(board[1][4] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return invalidMove();
            }
        case 7:
            if(board[2][0] == ' '){
                return true;
            } else{
                return invalidMove();
            }
        case 8:
            if(board[2][2] == ' '){
                return true;
            } else{
                return invalidMove();
            }
        case 9:
            if(board[2][4] == ' '){
                return true;
            } else{
                return invalidMove();
            }

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
        
    public static void playerMove(char [] [] board, int position) {
        
        char character = 'X';       
        boolean result = validateMove(position, board);
        while(!result) {
        
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            position = scan.nextInt();
            result = validateMove(position, board);
        }
        switch (position){
        case 1:
            board[0][0] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 2:
            board[0][2] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 3:
            board[0][4] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 4:
            board[1][0] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 5:
            board[1][2] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 6:
            board[1][4] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 7:
            board[2][0] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 8:
            board[2][2] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        case 9:
            board[2][4] = character;
            printBoard(board);
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }
    }
        
        
    

    public static void printBoard(char [] [] board) {   
        
        for(char [] row: board) {
            for(char column: row) { 
                System.out.print(column);   
            }
            System.out.println();   
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be updating `ergebnis` in your `while(!ergebnis)` loop?

Comment: First, you should write your code in english, especially the variable names, otherwise it gets really hard for non-German speakers to reason about it.

Comment: I edited it in English.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of things that could be improved with you code, for example: why do you have a method that just returns false (`invalidZug`)?

But to just answer your question, why don't you introduce a boolean called `playersTurn` which will be set to true if the input in the beginning is "Ja" and to false if the input is "Nein". You could then in the game loop always check whos' turn it is. If it's the players turn prompt him to give you input (using `playerZug()`), if it's the computers turn just let the computer play with `computerZug()`. Afterwards invert the boolean `playersTurn = !playersTurn;`
if done properly this will also resolve the problem with you print appearing twice as you can remove it once.

If you want the computers first turn to always be a without a two in it that means there are 4 possible fields left, just generate a number between 0 and 3 and map the different possibilities to the computer playing one of these possibilities.

You could have an if statement before the loop kind of like this:

```
if (!playersTurn) { //it's the computers turn first
    int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 4); //random number between 0 and 3
    switch (rand) {
    case 0:
        board[0][0] = computerKreis;
        break;
    case 1:
        board[0][2] = computerKreis;
        break;
    case 2:
        board[2][0] = computerKreis;
        break;
    case 3:
        board[2][2] = computerKreis;
        break;
    }
}
    
    while (true) { //while(true) loops should be avoided, introduce a variable that is set to false if the game finishes.
        printBoard(board);
        if (playersTurn) {
            ask the player...
        }
        else {
            computerZug();
        }
        playersTurn = !playersTurn;
    }
```

This is just to give you an idea, as your question seems like homework it is also you job to figure this out yourself ;), best of luck!